# How to override Quick Order model

Tags: magento2, extend, preference, override-model

I'm working on a Magento 2.2.3 B2B, with the Quick Order feature enabled, and I can't find a way to extend a method of the `Magento\QuickOrder\Model\Cart` model.

So far I tried the usual:
`MyCompany/MyModule/etc/di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\QuickOrder\Model\Cart"
    type="MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Cart"/>
```

and then in `MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Cart.php`:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model;

class Cart extends \Magento\QuickOrder\Model\Cart
{
    protected function _addAffectedItem($item, $code)
    {
        // My extended code
    }
}
```

But it's not working. I also tried using a plugin, but for some reason my code is being ignored. Any ideas of what's going on with this Model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution?  Our client has asked to extend the QuickOrder functionality to allow for a part_number which is currently added on as a custom product attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use before methods if you want your code to be executed first. Just follow along this documentation:
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thank you but as I mentioned I tried using before and after plugins, but those are being ignored also. It looks like some other Model is overriding all of my changes.